# drag and drop object like sticker ios

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I want to develop io application for making stickers using some predefined shapes(images)

I looked the example https://github.com/brynbellomy/iOS-DragAndDrop

it's nearly my requirements but when i start dragging an object it will be removed from there orignal position.

I need that the dragging object must be available at orignal position to again add it to sticker.

Please help me to solve this. Has anyone used above example or created sticker like view in ios then please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new sticker object at some point, which will remain behind when you drag the first one. You could create a new one in the same position every time one is dragged away, for example. If you do this at the right moment and set its Z-order appropriately you'll get the illusion of the infinite sticker pile I think you're looking for.